# Hide 'show more' button using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have button "Show more" on my WP site. By default 2 posts are shown, and on click on this button appears other 2 posts. So I need to check on page load, if there is more than 2 posts. It there is not, button hides. I use AJAX for this. But my code doesn't work.

**functions.php**

```
function buttonHide() {
   $posts_count = wp_count_posts()->publish;
   if ($posts_count <= 2) {
    echo '<script>function hideLoadMore(){$("#load-post").hide();}</script>';
     }
     // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_buttonHide', 'buttonHide');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_buttonHide', 'buttonHide');
```

**load.js**

```
$(function() {

        checkLoadButton();

        function checkLoadButton() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",


                data: ({               
                     action: 'buttonHide'
                }),
                type: "GET",
                success: function() {
                    if (hideLoadMore) {
                        hideLoadMore(); //function from functions.php
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't work'?

Comment: Nothing happens, in console `Uncaught ReferenceError: hideLoadMore is not defined` - so I think problem is in .php file

Comment: View-source could tell that. And echo $posts_count

Comment: `hideLoadMore(); //function from functions.php` - Are you trying to call a PHP function from a JS code? It's impossible.

Comment: @OfirBaruch no he is not. He echos `'<script>function hideLoadMore(){$("#load-post").hide();}</script>'` when needed

Comment: In .php you can see that this function is generated to js and it IS js function

Comment: Yea, noticed it just now. instead of `if(hideLoadMore)` use `if (typeof hideLoadMore == 'function') {`

Comment: That is not the problem. if (hideLoadMore) will work too

Comment: It is undefined anyway(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

functions.php

```
function buttonHide() {
   $posts_count = wp_count_posts()->publish;
   if ($posts_count <= 2) {


      $result['type'] = "success";
       $result['status'] = 'hide'  ;
       $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
        die();
     }else{

        $result['type'] = "success";
        $result['status'] = 'show'  ;
        $result = json_encode($result);
        echo $result;
        die();
     }


    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_buttonHide', 'buttonHide');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_buttonHide', 'buttonHide');


add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );

function my_script_enqueuer() {

   wp_localize_script( 'more_script', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'more_script' );

}
```

load.js

```
 function checkLoadButton() {
             jQuery.ajax({


            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: "buttonHide"},


             success: function(response) {
            if(response.type == "success") {


                if(response.status=="hide"){
                    jQuery("#load-post").hide();
                }else if(response.status=="show"){
                    jQuery("#load-post").show();
                }

            }
            else {
               alert("Error")
            }
         }
            });
        }

$(function() {
        checkLoadButton();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable ***hideLoadMore*** is indeed not defined.

If you expect this variable to be the response to your Ajax, you should correct your callback-function:

```
$(function() {
    checkLoadButton();

    function checkLoadButton() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: ({               
                 action: 'buttonHide'
            }),
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response) {
                    hideLoadMore(); //function from functions.php
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you want to get an function as result, you have to use JSONP as **accept:** -option in your AJAX

Comment: The crucial thing is, that you want to pass an `<script>` to your JS file. That will only work when you call the PHP-script with `dataType: "JSONP"`. This will return the whole `<script>` block you `echo` in your PHP. Otherwise you have to define an according function in your JS file and just `echo` an boolean variable if you want to call the `function`or not